# Error in eval(mapping$x, data) in R: Error in stats::model.frame(formula = x, data = y) : object 'x' not found GGally::GGpairs function

Tags: r, eval, ggally, ggpairs

I am trying to customize my ggpairs function and I for that I am using a data.frame that I have imported from keggle.
Here is a minumum reproducible example:

```
BMI = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Glucose = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 0.9, 0.5) 
example_df = data.frame(BMI, Glucose)
bla = function(data, mapping){
  x <- eval(mapping$x, data)
  y <- eval(mapping$y, data)
  return(cor.test(x,y))
}

bla(diabetes, aes(BMI, Glucose))
```

When I print `x` and `y` without the `return(cor.test(x,y))` I get the names of the columns I am working with. When I want to run the cor.test I get the following error:

```
Error in stats::model.frame(formula = x, data = y) : object 'x' not found
```

Here is the traceback:

```
6.
stats::model.frame(formula = x, data = y)
5.
eval(m, environment(formula))
4.
eval(m, environment(formula))
3.
cor.test.formula(x, y)
2.
cor.test(x, y)
1.
bla(diabetes, aes(BMI, Glucose))
```

Comment: Try `eval_data_col(data, mapping$x)` and similar for `y`

Comment: It worked! Everything is working now. What was the matter? I read in other questions that it had something to do with the environment.